# SignalR only works the first time it is called

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr

I have a *ASP.NET Core MVC 5* website. I am using *SignalR* to send "Notifications" from the model layer to the client / view.

If I open my *index page*, It uses *SignalR* to send a list of available cameras as they are discovered. I then again use *SignalR* to send images that the camera is taking on a different model. However, only the first one works.

If I navigate to `https://localhost:44303/camera/live/?IP=192.168.50.212` It starts sending images, but will not discover other cameras. If I navigate to the discovery first, the discovery works just fine.

In both the models, the line `Hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("method", data);` is executing. In both models, the *Hub* is defined as

```
public Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IHubContext<MasterHub> Hub { get; internal set; }`
```

and each model has a separate controller, that sets the hub context like so:

```
private readonly IHubContext<MasterHub> _hubContext;

public CameraController(IHubContext<MasterHub> hubContext)
{
    _hubContext = hubContext;
}
```

However, only the first one I navegate to works.

Do I have to close the *SignalR* connection after sending a message to use it again? If so, How would I do this?

both controllers look like:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Thermal_Screening.Hubs;
using Thermal_Screening.Models;


namespace Thermal_Screening.Controllers
{
    public class CameraController : Controller
    {
        public string CameraName;
        private readonly IHubContext<MasterHub> _hubContext;

        public CameraController(IHubContext<MasterHub> hubContext)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }

        public IActionResult Live(string IP)
        {
            CameraName = getCameraNameFromIP(IP); // doin it this way causes a 2s delay, should get ip in model

            return View(new CameraViewModel(IP) { Hub = _hubContext, IP = IP, CameraName = CameraName });
        }

        public IActionResult Settings(string IP)
        {
            CameraName = getCameraNameFromIP(IP);

            return View(new CameraViewModel(IP) { Hub = _hubContext, IP = IP, CameraName = CameraName });

        }

        public IActionResult Log(string IP)
        {
            CameraName = getCameraNameFromIP(IP);

            return View(new CameraViewModel(IP) { Hub = _hubContext, IP = IP, CameraName = CameraName });

        }

        private string getCameraNameFromIP(string IP)
        {
            WebClient x = new WebClient();
            string source = x.DownloadString("http://" + IP);
            return Regex.Match(source, @"\<title\b[^>]*\>\s*(?<Title>[\s\S]*?)\</title\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups["Title"].Value;
        }
    }
}
```

both viewmodels look like:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
using Flir.Atlas.Live.Discovery;
using Flir.Atlas.Live.Device;
using Flir.Atlas.Live;
using System.IO;
using Flir.Atlas.Image;
using System.Drawing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Thermal_Screening.Hubs;

namespace Thermal_Screening.Models
{
    public class CameraViewModel
    {


        public Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IHubContext<MasterHub> Hub { get; internal set; }

//removed for berevity

Hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("method", "data");
```

Comment: Please show enough code to reproduce the problem, not just snippets

Comment: @stuartd I have edited it.

Comment: any luck with this? I am stuck with same issue

Comment: @ParasSachapara I swiched to ASP.NET Framework, and it seemed to fix the issue. There are different packages for .net framework vs .net core signalr, make sure your signalr matches your platform.  If you must use .net core, I found it works to use the .net framework signalr package with ,net core framework.